# Como puedo determinar un limite numerico en un entry de tkinter

Tags: python

Hola me preguntaba como puedo establecer un limite de valor numerico en un entry de tkinter
este es mi código:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

nmsv = IntVar()
nms = Entry(Canvas, font=("poppins", 10), textvariable=nmsv)
nms.pack(pady=10, padx=15)

def amountlimit(nmsv):
    if nmsv <= 10:
        nmsv == 0
```

UTILIZO PYTHON 3.9.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hace mucho que ya no uso tkinter pero se me hizo más fácil con una variable en cadena que una en entero, si es que entendí bien, un ejemplo funcional:

```
from tkinter import *

def cambia(sv):
    valor=sv.get()
    try:
        if int(valor) >= 10:
            sv.set("0")
    except:
        sv.set("")
        
root = Tk()
sv = StringVar()
sv.trace("w", lambda nombre,index, mode, sv=sv: cambia(sv))
e = Entry(root, textvariable=sv)
e.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

en donde basicamente hago lo mismo y le agrego a la variable el método trace() que se usa para detectar cuando una variable es leída, cambia de valor o es borrada, en este caso con el parámetro "w" es cuando cambia.